# How can you optimize looping through an object with a large number of keys, removing the keys that contain the given string?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (key.indexOf(str) >= 0) {
        delete obj[key]
    }
}
```

Say your objects start getting very large e.g. 10,000 keys and you need to start thinking scale. Would there be any way to speed this up?

Comment: Nope, not really, other than *not* using objects with 10k keys.

Comment: If you know the likely numbers for how many you would be stripping out, you could actually do a performance comparison between deleting keys from objA or just creating a new objB and adding keys that wouldn't be screened out. Still does leave open question of why you expect a 10k key object bag.

Comment: `Object.keys(o).filter(/./.test, /str/).forEach(k=>delete o[k])` _might_ be faster, or at least scaleable by breaking up the operations

Comment: Could you expand a bit on your use case? Any potential optimization would involve more understanding of how these objects and their keys are created.

Comment: have you already encountered the real issues while iterating that object? maybe, some errors, "hangings" ?

Comment: Do you already have this map, or do you control the code that builds it, and then later needs to prune it? If it's the latter, you could likely do things with the structure of the keyset, especially if there's a small number of potential keywords, or you know the keywords to be pruned in advance.

Comment: If `str` is very long, building a suffix tree/array for `str` is likely to give better performance. If all keys are of the same length, you can build a hash table for `key.length`-long substrings and reduce string matching to hash table lookups. If `str` is short, your current algorithm may have better performance in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a performance test with two methods. It turns out that the results vary greatly from one browser to another.

On my box, **deleting keys** (method #1) in the original object is significantly slower in Firefox, slightly slower in Edge and slightly faster in Chrome.

On the other hand, **creating a new object** (method #2) runs with similar times on all browsers and is pretty fast. So, I think this 2nd method should be privileged.

The test object includes 50% of matching keys in average, so the test should be fair for both methods.

```js
var n, ts, obj, str = "abc";

// creating an object with 10000 keys
for(n = 0, obj = {}; n < 10000; n++) {
  obj["key" + n + (Math.random() < 0.5 ? str : '')] = Math.random();
}

// applying method #1
ts = performance.now();

for(var key in obj) {
  if(key.indexOf(str) >= 0) {
    delete obj[key]
  }
}

console.log('Method #1 : ' + (performance.now() - ts).toFixed(2) + 'ms');

// creating an object with 10000 keys
for(n = 0, obj = {}; n < 10000; n++) {
  obj["key" + n + (Math.random() < 0.5 ? str : '')] = Math.random();
}

// applying method #2
ts = performance.now();

var newObj = {};

Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) {
  return key.indexOf(str) == -1;
}).forEach(function(key) {
  newObj[key] = obj[key];
});

console.log('Method #2 : ' + (performance.now() - ts).toFixed(2) + 'ms');
```

Comment: This isn't surprising. If the collection of keys is a simple list, then deleting one will cause all the others to move up. So deleting a key becomes an O(n) operation. Doesn't take having to delete more than one or two keys before copying becomes very attractive.

Comment: Just to nitpick, you should really be subtracting `performance.now()`, not `Date.now()`. And considering this is only 3-5ms long, there's probably a significant amount of overhead involved in just calling `.indexOf()` and the timing functions `.now()`. You should increase the amount of keys being manipulated, and discuss the performance issues caused by iterating a string rather than doing a hashtable lookup to check whether each key is valid.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thank you for the `performance.now()` suggestion. This is updated. I don't think I should put too many iterations in this runnable example which may be executed on low-end devices, though. I'll leave it to the reader's initiative.

Comment: @JimMischel While your analysis perfectly describes what's happening in FIrefox, the results suggest that neither Edge nor Chrome are moving keys when one is deleted. They're probably using linked lists and just updating the pointers.

Comment: Just a precision about my latest comment: when doing more iterations, it turns out that method #1 runs in polynomial time in Firefox (validating the fact that delete[] runs in O(n)), and, as far as I can tell, in linear time in Edge & Chrome (suggesting that delete[] runs in O(1)).